# What if someone just thanked answerer instead of accepting that answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238620/i-was-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-20-from-ubuntu-18-04/1238665#1238665) recently and the questioner was helped by it. But instead of accepting the answer, he [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238620/i-was-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-20-from-ubuntu-18-04/1238665#comment2086709_1238665) on my answer:

> Hey thanks for your efforts I upgraded successfully

Which means he was able to solve his problem. But he didn't accept my answer. What can I do now?

Answer (score 16):

For the general case, accepting an answer is a privilege that is enjoyed only by the OP (original poster) of the question. If OP is a new user and presumably unaware of how accepting works, you may ask them (as [you've done here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238620/i-was-unable-to-update-to-ubuntu-20-from-ubuntu-18-04/1238665#comment2087385_1238665)); but if they decide not to accept any of the answers posted to their question, then nothing else can be done regarding it by the rest of us.

But particularly in this case, I don't think your answer actually solved OP's problem, they merely thanked you for your *efforts*. The comment should probably be read as

> Hey, thanks for your efforts. I upgraded successfully.

I think so because I noticed OP also posted [a self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239185/480481) explaining that *switching to the main server as the download source* solved the problem. I don't see anything mentioning this in your answer.

**Update:** Looks like OP accepted their own answer.

Comment: I think +1 for his efforts.

Comment: But how can he accept his own answer?

Comment: @sasuke What is that supposed to mean? There is neither a technical limitation to (except one cannot accept their own answer within 48 hours since the *question* is asked) nor a moral obligation against accepting own answer. One should accept an answer which solves their problem (and in the most helpful manner) *regardless* of who posted it.

Comment: @pomsky You can't accept your answers only in the 1st 48 hours? I didn't know that. Thanks. I have to accept some of my "Answer your own question" ones then... Thanks again...